# Access data from other SharePoint site in SharePoint Hosted Apps

Tags: sharepoint-addin, apps-development

I want to create one SharePoint Hosted App. In this app i have to access other SharePoint intranet site's list data, this site is in different web application. 
    My apps site url is  http://appssite.mycompany.com and web application where i want to access data is http://intranet.mycompany.com. Both this sites exist on different web applications.

I want the way, we can access other SharePoint web (not hosted web) data using CSOM in SharePoint Hosted apps.

Answer (score 0):

If both the sites are not in the same tenancy or web application, then a SharePoint-hosted app cannot get data from the other site. This is by design. It is for security reasons to block cross-domain scripting attacks. You will need to use a SharePoint provider-hosted app or a SharePoint autohosted app.

[Access denied, from an app, when getting List items from a different web applcation](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/72283/access-denied-from-an-app-when-getting-list-items-from-a-different-web-applcat)

[Using JSOM or REST get list items stored in a different web application](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/109231/using-jsom-or-rest-get-list-items-stored-in-a-different-web-application)

Comment: Thanks Anchal! If this is true then it's bad news for me because we lots of site like leave mgmt, room booking, cab booking etc on other web applications.